# Mapping magic numbers to enum values, and vice-versa

Tags: java, enums, magic-numbers

In the database I'm using this with there are magic numbers which I want to map to the `State` enum, and vice-versa.  I'm intrigued by the static declaration of `undefined.code = 0`.  What does this declaration, if that's what it is, actually do?

```
package net.bounceme.dur.data;

public enum State {

    undefined(0), x(1), o(2), c(3), a(4), l(5), d(6);
    private int code = 0;

    static {
        undefined.code = 0;
        x.code = 1;
        o.code = 2;
        c.code = 3;
        a.code = 4;
        l.code = 5;
        d.code = 6;
    }

    State(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    public static State getState(int code) {
        for (State state : State.values()) {
            if (state.getCode() == code) {
                return state;
            }
        }
        return undefined;
    }

}
```

Currently, the usage for this enum factory method is as so:

```
  title.setState(State.getState(resultSet.getInt(5)));
```

but I would be interested in any and all alternatives.

Comment: Why would you do this? Just change `private int code = 0;` to `private final int code;` and assign it once. What is the point of the `static` block?

Comment: It might help to think of `enum`s as regular objects with a guaranteed singleton property. So `code` is just a field for a `State` object, and `undefined.code` is accessing that field for a particular instance of a `State` object.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I don't know what the point of the static block is, that's part of what I'm asking.  It's used in a similar question to mine, and appears to...assign values?

Comment: The static block doesn't serve any purpose. It does what the constructor already does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've removed the useless static block and improved the inverse function.

```
public enum State {

private static Map<Integer,State> int2state = new HashMap<>();

undefined(0), x(1), o(2), c(3), a(4), l(5), d(6);
private int code;

State(int code) {   // executed for *each* enum constant
    this.code = code;
    int2state.put( code, this ); 
}

public int getCode() {
    return this.code;
}

public static State getState(int code) {
    return int2state.get(code);
}
}
```

If the "code" integers are definitely ordinals from 0 up, you can omit the Constructor parameter, private int code and map like so:

```
int2state.put( this.ordinal(), this );
```

Comment: how is the map populated?  I will have to print it out to see, but it **seems** to me that only a **single** entry is made into the map.  How does it have **all** the mapping entries?

Comment: see my second edit - comment on the constructor. This one is executed once for each enum value.

Comment: The constructor is called multiple times, once per enum instance. So the map is fully populated. You should accept this answer Thufir, it's correct and efficient.

Answer (score 2):

In the code you posted, the static block line

```
undefined.code = 0;
```

It accesses the enumerated constant `undefined`, and blindly sets the value of the mutable field `code` from `0` to `0`. Basically, the constant was defined here

```
undefined(0)
```

with a code of `0`. Likewise with `x` and `1`. And so on.

Answer (score 2):

Well it really does the same thing as the constructor - sets the `code` associated each enum value.

In your example, the `static { ... }` block is superfluous (unnecessary) and should probably be removed since it duplicates the line starting with `underfined(0)`.

The point where `Enum` usage gets tricky is with the lookup (in your case, `getState(...)` method). The `case` statement here really duplicates the code a third time, and you might be better to build a `Map` that takes a code (`int`) and returns the enum (`State`) - just google around, there are plenty of examples on how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Just a hint. It is much more readable to change your `getState(int)` method to

```
    public static State getState(int code) {
        for (State state : State.values()) {
            if (state.getCode() == code) {
                return state;
            }
        }
        return undefined; 
    }
```

Comment: @Iaune's answer for `getState(int)` is actually even faster and better.